# Why does Sean Carroll claims that decoherence explains world branching in the Everett interpretation?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, decoherence

In a recent [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvMo7_RxccY&t=1009s), Sean Carroll explicitly claims that, in Everett, world branching
occurs when two decoherence makes worlds "so different" that interference will
no more become observable between them, or when they will no longer be able
to interfere for some reason.
I am not really sure what that could exactly mean, but I do not understand why
two orthogonal eigenstates of the universal wavefunction would be forbidden to
interfere because, in principle, one can always imagine an "huge" unitary transformation  that could "rotate" such states towards a different basis,
just like we could rotate $(1/\sqrt 2)|1\rangle + (1/\sqrt 2)|0\rangle$ into $|1\rangle$ using an $H$ gate.
What am I missing?

Comment: This may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/parallel-worlds-probably-exist-heres-why/339179977597625/)

Comment: @Luis Caires Aren't you just asking how decoherence works? This is quite a large subject and textbooks are written about it.

Comment: Some comments removed; comments are for criticizing and improving the post being commented upon, not for voicing your opinion on the general content of the question. If you want to answer the question, please write an answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Pointing to a general and trivial critique of Everett is well within the range of the information the OP should get IMHO, especially since "state" in quantum mechanics always refers to an ensemble measurement. It can never be a property of the single quantum mechanical system. That there can be no universal wave function (despite continuous claims in the literature about it) is also fairly obvious. I don't know why you are criticizing this? My first comment clearly pointed out that the motivation of Sean Carrol is also beyond the reach of physics. Is it not?

Comment: @FlatterMann I'm not making a judgement of whether or not you're *right*, I'm saying that comments are not the correct place for this critique of Everett. Perhaps you should review the [commenting guidelines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment): I, for one, do not see how your comments guide OP in improving the post, nor do I consider them minor or transient. If you think this critique of Everett answers the question, leave it as an answer; in any case I don't see why it would belong in the comments here. If you disagree with this, I suggest you take it to [meta].

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's fair.

Answer (score 1):

The decoherence argument is statistical. It tries to borrow the same reasoning by which the *reversible* laws of collisions between individual molecules lead to *irreversible* effects in accordance with the second law of thermodynamics. If you start with all the molecules of a gas in one side of the box, they will spread out to occupy both sides of the box equally. If you then reverse the velocity of every molecule, the reversibility of the Newtonian laws of collisions implies they would all spontaneously bounce back into the same side of the box. We never see this sort of thing happening in practice, not because the laws of molecular collisions forbid it, but because it is fantastically unlikely to happen that the velocities of $10^{23}$ particles should by chance be in one of the vanishingly rare configurations that unscrambled entropy.

The idea is that when entangling interactions start to involve astronomical numbers of particles, the probability of them ever spontaneously untangling back to pure uncorrelated states rapidly approaches zero. It's not theoretically impossible - as you say, some huge rotation in Hilbert space could do it - but it would be like trying to herd all the gas molecules into one side of the box.

Comment: Decoherence doesn't require a large number of quanta. It happens already by coupling to a single additional quantum. That the world is uncertain doesn't require any of that, anyway. Relativity couples local physics to the volume of vacuum that's inside the local observer's forward light cone, including the surface of the light cone itself. Since the state on the forward light cone is not knowable (it travels away from us at the speed of light and we can't "catch" it ever again), there is necessarily a continuous loss of information about the local state going on in every relativistic system.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't think any of that is correct - but I don't think there is any point in me arguing with you about it. (By the way, if anyone *does* happen to read Everett's thesis (highly recommended!) they'll see that starting from the second sentence Everett is first presenting a summary of the *standard* interpretation found in textbooks before going on to explain why he thinks it is wrong and inconsistent. So you're not criticising MWI in your comment above, you're criticising the 'standard' theory.)

Comment: How would the local observer know how much energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge has been transferred, already? That information is only available to observers who are covering increasingly larger distances to the original system and it can only be retrieved at the speed of light, hence it is never available "here and now". It can only be made available in the future. To me this is trivial. With regards to Everett's thesis... am I asking too much by pointing to a trivial mistake in the second sentence? I don't think that reaches any level of "extra work" by standards of science.

Comment: @FlatterMann https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

Comment: The local observer doesn't *need* to know how much energy or momentum has been transferred elsewhere. The Everett Interpretation is an entirely local theory - there is no 'action at a distance' involved. All the information needed is available 'here and now' - that's one of the major selling points in its favour. Do you have any comment on my answer based on *what I said*, or what the actual MWI as Everett or Carroll presented it says, as opposed to your own made up version of it?

Comment: @alanf No offense, but that paper makes the exact same mistake as Everett's original paper. It identifies wave functions (i.e. descriptions of all possible outcomes) with actual outcomes. We have the exact same situation in classical mechanics with the construction of the Hamiltonian flow. It is possible to extract valuable information about a system by looking at the entirety of its dynamics at the same time. That we can do this on paper for e.g. the solar system does not mean that all possible forms of the solar system exist independently at the same time.

Comment: If we extract the information locally, then there is no system. Measurement in quantum mechanics means that we remove the energy from the system. An atom that is embedded in a (theoretical) detector that measures the position of its electrons all the time is not an atom. It's a dead system. The reason for the structure of quantum mechanics is based on the fact that these systems are sufficiently isolated from the measurement to have a reversible dynamic at all. We need both "a system" and a sufficiently isolated (weak) "measurement system" to have quantum mechanics.

Comment: *"It identifies wave functions (i.e. descriptions of all possible outcomes) with actual outcomes."* I'll repeat, this is *not* MWI, this is the *standard textbook explanation* of QM that Everett was criticising/replacing. The claim that the wavefunction is simply documenting the ensemble is untenable because might-have-beens cannot exhibit interference. *"Measurement in quantum mechanics means that we remove the energy from the system."* No it doesn't. But that's all off topic. Can you stick to the subject, please?

Comment: The Copenhagen interpretation spells out how to extract actual physics from a system: it can only done through the Born rule (which mimics the irreversible measurement process) and not from the wave function alone. Moreover, the system can only have a single state after the measurement: the one that was measured. That single quanta produce interference is also not part of a well written textbook. What shows "interference effects" is the ensemble. As an experimentalist I always had to remove energy from the system. Can you show me how I get past thermal noise without a quantum that is >kT?

Comment: @FlatterMann - your wrong turn is that you try to criticise MWI from an “orthodox” i.e. *epistemic* perspective. Everett introduces a new perspective, that a quantum state vector plus its deterministic unitary time evolution describes *reality* in a single system prior to measurement (not just measurement results in an ensemble). What you call “wrong” is the fact that there are two different interpretations. In order to understand Everett et al. you have to accept that their perspective *differs* from your “orthodox” view - but is *not* wrong.

Comment: @TomS Everett's thesis is already wrong in its second sentence in which he claims that the wave function describes one system rather than an ensemble of systems. He may have copied that mistake from von Neumann without even thinking about it. It is not surprising that he ends up with an infinite number of parallel universes since he couldn't even distinguish one copy of a system from an infinite number of copies. The reasoning behind MWI is a completely trivial mistake that is very easy to spot IMHO.

Comment: You don't see the difference between "X is wrong" and "I don't understand X". The discussion is pointless and should be ended.